# Cloned Form Symfony2 (CraueFlowFormBundle)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, bundle

I use *CraueFlowForm* for Symfony2 (I use 2.6.4) with some sub-form.
In one of these sub-form I have a problem.
I have a new form field that is cloned from a field I filled ('participants') in that appears when I submit my form, so means I display another form after submitting the form in the first place.

```
    $builder
        ->add('date', 'datetime', array(
            'label'       => "Date de tweet : ",
            "date_widget" => 'single_text',
            "time_widget" => 'single_text',
            "date_format" => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'required'    => false
        ))
        ->add('participants', 'number', array(
            'label'    => "Nombre de participants au déclenchement : ",
            'required' => false,
            'mapped'   => true
        ))
        ->add('send', 'submit', array(
            'label' => "Programmez votre tweet",
            "attr"  => array(
                'class' => "btn-primary"
            )
        ));
```

Thank you in advance